# Как обновить товар в woocommerce через код?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Проблема в том что когда я обновляю _sale_price через update_post_meta();
данные заносятся в админпанель, а на сайте не обновляются, но когда я нажимаю на кнопку обновить(в админпанели), на сайте появляются нужные мне данные. Как можно обновить товар через код?

Comment: Покажите код. В двух словах: там надо вызывать product->save

Answer (score 0):

Всё, я решил проблему. Нужно было обновить и _price и _sale_price